# Show that $\int _E f=0$ for each subset $E $ of $\mathbb R $ of finite Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a bounded Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int_a^b f =0$ for all real $a,b.$

Show that $\int _E f=0$ for each subset $E $ of $\mathbb R $ of finite Lebesgue
measure

Actually I am new to measure theory.So maybe above is simple I can't proceed

Comment: I suppose you mean $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx =0$? And any thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f.$ Then $F\equiv 0$ from the given hypothesis. Therefore $F'\equiv 0.$ But $F'(x) = f(x)$ for a.e. $x$ by the Legesgue differentiation theorem. Thus $f=0$ a.e., hence $\int_E f = 0$ for any measurable set $E.$ (Using a big gun there, but thought I'd toss this in.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have, $$f = f^+-f^-$$ where $f^+$ and $f^-$ denote the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively. By assumption, the ($\sigma$-finite) measures

$$\nu(dx) := f^+(x) \, dx \qquad \mu(dx) := f^-(x) \, dx$$

satisfy

$$\mu((a,b)) = \nu((a,b)).$$

Conclude from the uniqueness of measure theorem that $\mu = \nu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Given any open set $O \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \{I_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ disjoint collection of open intervals. Thus, $\int_{O}{f}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{I_k}{f}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{0}=0$. Thus, from our assumption we get that the integral over any open set is zero. Similarly, we get for any $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ closed $\int_{K}{f}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}{f}-\int_{\mathbb{R}-K}{f}=0$. Define $F^+=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ and $F^-=\{x:f(x)<0\}$. Using inner regularity of Lebesgue measure it is not hard to see that $m(F^+)=m(F^-)=0$ and thus $f=0$ a.e. Thus, we get for any measurable set E we get that$\int_{E}{f}=0$.

Comment: I was going to mention on your recently deleted question, no two subgroups can be disjoint (they both contain the identity), and the intersection of two finite index subgroups must also have finite index (standard textbook exercise). For $\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2$ to be smallest, the index $[G:\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2]$ must be largest - it attains the upper bound $[G:\Gamma_1][G:\Gamma_2]$ if and only if $G=\Gamma_1\Gamma_2$, so your intuition was onto something.

Comment: @runway44 cheers I am going to open a new question as that one was poorly phrased which describes the more specific scenario I am interested in.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We can find a countable collection of open intervals $I_k$ such that
$$
E \subset U = \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb N} I_k, \qquad
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(I_k) \right) - m(E) < \epsilon
$$
Now, note that 
$$
\left| 
\int_U f\,dx - \int_E f\,dx 
\right| = 
\left|
\int_{U \setminus E} f\,dx
\right|
$$

---

**Alternative:** Show that $\int_U f\,dx = 0$ whenever $U$ is a $G_\delta$ set.  Then, note that there is a $U$ such that $E \subset U$ with $m(U \setminus E) = 0$.

Comment: using $\int _a^b f=0$ I can conclude that $\int _u f=0$  is $\int _{U\setminus E} f=0$ ? because $m(U\setminus E)=m(U)-m(E)=0$